# 500 Internal Server Error for Post Request

Tags: json, angular, http, server

I am trying to save data from the UI form via API endpoint. I got 500 Internet server error for that API request.
When I check on payload, I can see all the data that I want to send.
Not sure how to solve 500 Internal server error

```js
{
   "OrderDetail":{
      "Item1":0,
      "Item2":0,
      "Item3":0
   },
   "OrderNo":251,
}
```

Comment: 500 internal server issue means that your code is having an error and broke down during execution.

Comment: What is your APIEndpoint? It might be incorrect or your payload is incorrect

Comment: `500` is  a server side error.  If you're sure the POST data is in the format the server expects, there's nothing you can do in your Angular code to resolve the issue.  You need to debug the server code.

Comment: check your API arguments need. Are you sure OrderDetails is an object and not an Array?